# Use Sharepoint url parameter in PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

I am using a modern SharePoint site and have a few PowerApps embedded using the PowerApps web part. The parameter being passed to all three is the same, the "GroupName". I am reusing this app on several (200+) pages and they all work fine as long as the parameter I am passing is hardcoded into the URL.

```
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/default-xxxx?tenantId=xxxxx&GroupName=Group1
```

I want to use a url parameter in the SharePoint page, ie.

```
https://sharepoint.com/sites/SupportSite/SitePages/SupportPage.aspx?GroupNameParam=Group1
```

And then reference the parameter in the PowerApp URL.

```
https://apps.powerapps.com/play/e/default-xxxx?tenantId=xxxxx&GroupName=Param("GroupNameParam")
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

You can read SharePoint URL query string parameters using any of the SharePoint out of the box web parts.

Also, you will have to pass the URL query string parameter to Power Apps URL in Power Apps web part manually.